# ThingsBoard Rule Chains RPC Call Request

Tags: iot, thingsboard

After give a try of ThingsBoard [RPC Call Sample](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/rpc-request-tutorial/), I found that "ROTATING SYSTEM" device can get message from v1/devices/me/rpc/request after it publish a message to v1/devices/me/telemetry by itself;

If Rule Chains transform messages from other device, for example, update metadata.deviceName and metadata.deviceType from others to "ROTATING SYSTEM", "ROTATING SYSTEM" device cannot get any message.

[RPC Call Sample](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/rpc-request-tutorial/) mentioned that "WIND DIRECTION SENSOR" device send messages to ThingsBoard Server, after Rule Chains magic, "ROTATING SYSTEM" device can get RPC messages; but according to my experiment, it can't, "ROTATING SYSTEM" only get trigged after it send messages by itself to ThingsBoard.

So, my questions is, what is the best practice of Rule Chains on ThingsBoard Server to implement "deviceA trig deviceB"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, if you want "deviceA trig deviceB", you should create a relation between deviceA and deviceB, then add a rule node "change the originator" to change the originator from deviceA to deviceB.